# Error Code: 50005- Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, universal-analytics

There terribly slow performance of GA recently, this was the error returned after waiting for several minutes for a custom report to load.

Facing an error code: 50005

Checked in google for the solution, but the same query is left un answered.
Can any one let me know if you faced this problem and solution?

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/-nCGKp1jqVE

Comment: I had seen this before. If I remember right, it is an internal error related to Google data. I was able to come back later and the error was gone.

Comment: @closetnoc .. so does it mean that the error would auto solve , or should i do any data change manually?

Comment: This should resolve on it's own. There is nothing you can do but wait. In my case, I did not have to wait too long. It just may be that some data is missing and a report could not be generated as a result. It could be a simple lag time in updating the database.

Comment: @closetnoc . Thnk you.. Its working fine now. But the reports were still very slow. Any idea for this?

Comment: Also @closetnoc .. your answer helped me.. can you post the same in answer?

Comment: I found Google Analytics rather frustrating this morning myself. Sometimes it is a bit slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closetnoc's comment answers my question:

> This should resolve on it's own. There is nothing you can do but wait. In my case, I did not have to wait too long. It just may be that some data is missing and a report could not be generated as a result. It could be a simple lag time in updating the database.